# Command line to swich to another open an existing open window rather than opening new one

Tags: windows, command-line, internet-explorer

I have a POS application that will allow a call to another application.  I have a need to have an Internet Explorer window open and switch to it.  The command that I am using opens a new Internet Explorer window when run:

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```

Is there any way to get the command to open the existing open window?

Comment: I don't think this can be done via command-line, but it can be set globally in Internet Options.  (i.e.:  Open *all* links from external applications in the current window.)

Answer (score 0):

If familiar with code, you could use the user32.dll method "SetForegroundWindow":
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetForegroundWindow

You could then just switch window to the new one when it opens? There's an example of pInvoking from managed code on the MS site. Just switch the code for the specifics. 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSPInvokeDll-23a75c51

The supported CLI switches for Internet explorer can be found here (doesn't look like there's one that helps you):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330728(v=vs.85).aspx